# How can I dynamically define forms.IntegerField's min_value parameter?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am working with Django and its Forms classes.

I have created a Form with a single `forms.IntegerField` and I want to define its `min_value` parameter dynamically:

```
class BiddingForm(forms.Form):
    bidding_form = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, help_text="€", label="Bid")
```

Right now, it is statically set to `1`. I have tried to overwrite the `__init__()` function and pass in a `min_value` there. But since `bidding_form` is a class variable, I cannot use the resulting instance variable `min_value` on it:

```
class BiddingForm(forms.Form):
    min_value = 1

    def __init__(self, min_value):
        super().__init__()
        self.min_value = min_value

    bidding_form = forms.IntegerField(min_value=min_value, help_text="€", label="Bid")
```

As of my understanding, above class creates an instance variable `min_value` inside of `__init__()` which just shadows the class variable `min_value` and it ultimately results in `min_value` being `1` in the `bidding_form`'s declaration.
Since I have little understanding of Python and Django, I have not yet found a solution to this.
So, how can I dynamically define `forms.IntegerField`'s `min_value` parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You override the `min_value` of the field:

```
from django.core import validators MinValueValidator

class BiddingForm(forms.Form):
    bidding_form = forms.IntegerField(help_text='€', label='Bid')

    def __init__(self, *args, min_value=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        bidding_form = self.fields['bidding_form']
        bidding_form.min_value = min_value
        if min_value is not None:
            bidding_form.validators.append(MinValueValidator(min_value))
            bidding_form.widget.attrs['min'] = min_value
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Unfortunately, I have encoutered 2 problems. When I pass `self` to `super().__init()` I am getting `'BiddingForm' object has no attribute 'get'`. When I leave it, the site is shown but the `min_value` is ignored and my `IntegerField` can now have any value. How is that?

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is:

```
class BidForm(forms.Form):
    bid = forms.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, min_bid_value=0, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BidForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['bid'].widget.attrs['min'] = min_bid_value
```

You can call it like :

```
BidForm(min_bid_value=145)
```

and form won't let user enter number **less** than **145**.

Answer (score -1):

i dont think so but you can do check the length of the specified field before you check `if form.is_valid():`. like: `if len(form.cleaned_data['field']) < min:`